# Get the latest saved version of file from db in cake php

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, mysqli

I am new to cake php . I have notes saved on db . every time the user edit this note it saved as new version in the db like 1.0,1.1,1.2...... Now issue is i want to select the notes but with the highest version . i have a hasmany relationship .these notes are related to project. but i have tried is using `finderQuery` in my relationship like

my project model relationship is

```
public $hasMany = array(
        'Notes' => array(
            'className' => 'Notes',
            'foreignKey' => 'project_id',
            'dependent' => true,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => 'Notes.version desc',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        )
);
```

I also tried it with limit as 1 `'limit' => '1',` but the.n it shows only 1 record .
i found that it can be done with `finderQuery` .so i used this like

```
'Notes' => array(
            'className' => 'Notes',
            'foreignKey' => 'project_id',
            'dependent' => true,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => 'Notes.version desc',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => 'SELECT Notes.* FROM ce_notes AS Notes WHERE Notes.version="select max(Notes.version) from ce_notes"',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        )
```

it shows me null result .

**update**

if i use static version in condition like

```
public $hasMany = array(
        'Notes' => array(
            'className' => 'Notes',
            'foreignKey' => 'project_id',
            'dependent' => true,
            'conditions' => 'Notes.version=1.1', // here if Notes.version=max(Notes.version) can work 
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => 'Notes.version desc',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        ),
```

I am not finding the way to do this . although i can perform this with core `mysqli` query but i want to use cakephp's standard . please help me
[image]

Comment: your first $hasMany relation is correct. I think you are doing something wrong in another place...

Comment: then it is showing all results with all versions

Comment: if i use lilit 1 it shows only one record check screenshot http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/370655/23c2393354a9a868b03a58823dbadaac

Comment: you need only highest version right?

Comment: yes right ... like if i have 1.0, 1.1,1.3 and 1.4 version then i want to show only 1.4 th version

Comment: `i can perform this with [this sql]` - what query gives you the results that you want? "What's this as a find call?" is an easier question to understand than what you've currently asked.

Comment: not getting you . what you need from my side??

Comment: "what query gives you the results that you want?". You're probably going to find that your current schema is working against you. It's a lot easier if instead of get-last-version you have a boolean field on your notes to check whether they are latest or not, which is updated whenever a new version is stored.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this with my custom query . anybody can answer if there is a better way to do this . My controller functions is

```
 public function admin_view($id = null)
    {
        $this->Project->id = $id;
        if (!$this->Project->exists())
        {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid project'));
        }
        $project = $this->Project->find('first', array(
            'conditions' => array('Project.id' => $id),
            'contain' => array('Client', 'Phase','Notes')));
        $query="SELECT  `Notes`.`id` ,  `Notes`.`project_id` ,  `Notes`.`version` ,  `Notes`.`title` ,  `Notes`.`slug` ,  `Notes`.`comment_count` ,  `Notes`.`description` ,  `Notes`.`created` , `Notes`.`modified` ,  `Notes`.`project_id` 
            FROM  `EB`.`ce_notes` AS  `Notes` 
            WHERE  `Notes`.`project_id` = ('".$id."') 
            AND  `Notes`.`version` = ( 
            SELECT MAX(  `Notes`.`version` ) 
            FROM  `EB`.`ce_notes` AS  `Notes` 
            WHERE  `Notes`.`project_id` = ('".$id."') ) 
            ORDER BY  `Notes`.`version`";
       $notes= $this->Project->query($query);       
        $this->set(array('project'=>$project,'notes'=>$notes));
    }
```

model relations ship is

```
public $hasMany = array(
        'Notes' => array(
            'className' => 'Notes',
            'foreignKey' => 'project_id',
            'dependent' => true,
            'conditions' => '',
            'group' => 'Notes.version',
            'order' => 'Notes.version desc',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        ),
        'Notescomment' => array(
            'className' => 'Notescomment',
            'foreignKey' => 'note_id',
            'dependent' => true,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => 'Notescomment.created desc',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        ),
        'Phase' => array(
            'className' => 'Phase',
            'foreignKey' => 'project_id',
            'dependent' => true,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => 'Phase.position asc',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        ),
        'Notification' => array(
            'className' => 'Notification',
            'foreignKey' => 'project_id',
            'dependent' => true,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => 'Notification.created desc',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        )

    );

    /**
     * Contains this model's hasAndBelongsTo entity associations
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Client' => array(
            'className' => 'Client',
            'joinTable' => 'projects_clients',
            'foreignKey' => 'project_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'client_id',
            'unique' => 'keepExisting',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'deleteQuery' => '',
            'insertQuery' => ''
        ),
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'joinTable' => 'projects_users',
            'foreignKey' => 'project_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'user_id',
            'unique' => 'keepExisting',
            'with' => 'ProjectsUser',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'deleteQuery' => '',
            'insertQuery' => ''
        ),
    );
```

Comment: `My controller functions is` sql in a controller... :sadpanda:. Why don't you put the bare sql query (i.e. the query you could copy and paste into mysql directly) in the question so the question is clear ;)?

Comment: you are saying that i should use simple mysql query rather than cake php method??

Comment: .... no. I asked "what [sql] gives you the results that you want?" Because having a query and converting it to a find call is unambiguous and doesn't require understanding anything about your application.

Comment: the sql query i used in my answer giving me the exact result . if you know a way to convert this with cake php relation model then it will appreciated . thanx

Comment: You seem to be wilfully misinterpreting my comments. While you've put the query in this answer it's not in the question and not formatted as sql - since it's embedded in php code. It should not be necessary to read an answer (or comment) to understand the question. Anyway.. happy coding.